# SurfaceView horizontal scrolling

Tags: android, graph, scroll, surfaceview

I'm writing an application which will create a graph and draw it on a SurfaceView. Eventually the graph needs to be able to update live but for now I want the SurfaceView to be scrollable horizontally so that the user can see all the data. Is this possible?

Comment: can't you put on a Horizontal scrollView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place your custom view inside a horizontal scroll view as a separeate class. When you create an instace of your custom graph view you tell it to size itself according to the width of the graph by overriding the onMeasure method:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {     
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);      

    this.setMeasuredDimension(graphWidth, graphHeight);
}

graphWidth = barLenghtInPixels * barCount + extraSpaceInPixels;
```

You can place your customView in an xml layout using a custom tag like `<com.myApplication.GraphView...>` or use `myScrollView.addView(myCustomView)` and add it into the `HorizontalScrollView`, before you call `setContentView(myLayout)`.

Comment: When I try to place my custom view inside a horizontal scroll view and run the application it crashes, adb tells me that this is due to a null pointer exception. Do you have any idea why?   
   
     GraphView graphView;
    HorizontalScrollView myScrollView = new    HorizontalScrollView(this);  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        graphView = new GraphView(this);
        
        myScrollView.addView(graphView);
        setContentView(myScrollView);
    }
}

Comment: You can set some blocks of code as comments in order to find which part is causing it - simplify code to find the error. You would have to paste the code of GraphView and your activity in your question in order for me to know more what is going on.

Comment: "HorizontalScrollView myScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(this)" should be within onCreate.

Answer (score 1):

Place a HorizontalScrollView element inside surface view. Look at gatherTransparentRegion(Region region) in the [HorizontalScrollView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

Comment: to show my surfaceView I have extended it in code rather than used xml. How could I go about putting a HorizontalScrollView inside it?

Comment: Not sure maybe this will help http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg45804.html